# How can i put more than 3 arguments in a for loop?

Tags: c#, loops, arguments

I need something like this

```
for (int epsilon = 0; omega >= epsilon; epsilon += 1; char gamma = 'a'; gamma <= 'z'; gamma++)
```

But ofcourse it gives an error. Is something like this even possible?

Comment: I get what you want to do except one thing: when do you want the loop to end? Do you want it to end if both condition are true? Or just one of them is true?

Comment: try to declare variables outside for and use them for it, like : `char gamma;
int epsilon;
for (epsilon = 0, gamma = 'a'; omega >= epsilon || gamma <= 'z'; epsilon++, gamma++)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the loop like that:

```
char gamma = 'a';
for ( int epsilon = 0; omega >= epsilon && gamma <= 'z'; epsilon += 1, gamma++ )
{
}
```

Declaration of a loop indexers must be the same type, for example:

```
for ( int index1 = 0, index2 = 0; index1 < value1 && index2 < value2; index1++, index2 +=5 )
{
}
```

So we need to choose one type for the loop and declare others before.

But increments and condition can be mixed.